# HTML Select - use current selection value later in HTML, with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have an HTML selection dropdown that I create with Flask.  Next to this drop down, I have another that I'd like to make dependent on the choice chosen in the first one.

index.html

```
<div id="search_terms">
    <select onchange="refresh_selection()" id="query_selection">
        {% for term in search_terms %}
        <option value="{{term}}">{{term}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <select id="news_date_selection">
    {% if [THE OPTION SELECTED ABOVE] in html_files %}
        <option value="{{file}}">{{file}}</option>
    {% endif %}
    </select>
</div>
```

The idea is to use a function in my Flask .py file, to generate a list of file names (`html_files`).

Depending on the selection in the `query_selection` select, the `html_files` will be different.

So, if the `query_selection` choice is "Gotham", I want that Flask conditional statement to be

```
{% if "Gotham" in html_files %}
```

(If this is possible without Flask, let me now! ...could I squeeze in a jQuery script right there maybe, `$("#query_selection).on("change", function(){})` or something like that?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Ajax for that. You are in the right direction. use the `$("#query_selection).on("change", function(){})` to make an ajax call with the selected value of the first select box to an endpoint that will return the options for the second select box

see code example:

your JS file:

```
$('#select1').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: url, // this is the variable we declared in the template file
            data: $('#select1 option:selected').val(),
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false
        }).done(function (res) {
            // assuming res is the options for the second select filed 
            // append them to the second select
        });
    });
```

in your flask views.py file (or however you named it), make an endpoint to listen for the ajax call and return the options

```
from flask import json
@app.route('/get_options', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def get_options():
    select1_value = request.data

    # make a query with the selected value

    return json.dumps(query_results)
```

Add this tp your HTML template

```
<script>
 var url = "{{url_for('get_options')}}";
</script>
```

Comment: That's where I'm getting stuck.  That AJAX code goes in my `.js` file, yes?  Once I get the selection's value, how do I send that *back* to the HTML?

Comment: Hm, so I was able to get jQuery to get me the change value.  Now, I can't figure out how to put the javascript variable in to that Flask `if` statement... hmm

Comment: I have updated my answer to give you an idea of what needs to be done with some code examples

Comment: Thanks! When I try that, I get `url_for is not defined` in the console on the JS file.  In the views.py, to test it I just changed the return to `json.dumps(select1_value)` if that matters?

Comment: It is not defined since your code is in a separate JS file. In your HTML template write a script tag and declare a JS variable `var url = "{{url_for('get_options')}}"`. Then place the `url` variable in your ajax call url parameter. See my updated answer with the example

Comment: Aha!  Thanks so much, I think I'm getting it!  I was able to get the selected value to javascript.  Now, how do I pass that back to Flask, so I can do `{% if [selected option] in file %}`?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Once you got the selected value and it is sent to your backend (flask python code) you can run a query against your database that will return the filtered options based on the selected value. Then you build the second select using javascript and not jinja. Your template is only being rendered once on page load. you cannot change the DOM without using javascript.

Comment: Thanks so much for sticking with this one - thanks to your help, I have a much better understanding of what I'm trying to do.  Your last comment clarified things greatly!  The code you provided answered the question as I posted here, so many thanks :D :D

Comment: My pleasure :) happy I was able to help